# How to remove driver's side front door handle on a Mercedes Benz 2007 A-class W169?

Tags: mercedes-benz, locks, door

I am stuck trying to remove the door lock barrel from the inner mounted door module on the driver's side front door of my Mercedes Benz 2007 A-class W169.

I have undone the Torx T15 screw from the door outer edge, and the Torx T15 screw seen from the small hole in the door frame which is on the rear of the barrel lock. The barrel is loose but will not come out, and until this is removed I can not remove the door module.

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the same problem on a late 2005 W169. Note you do not need to remove the door card if you just want to remove the door lock cylinder and exterior handle.
Once you've loosened the bolt holding the cylinder accessed from the side of the door (On ours it was a T20 - T15 would work but there's a chance of rounding off the head) there is a catch above the bolt head which basically is still holding the cylinder. This needs to be pushed down so it covers the bolt head, this will then allow the cylinder to be pulled out. 
You access this using a thin screwdriver in the same way you undid the T15 and flip the catch down. It pivots from the left over the head of the bolt.
If you shine a torch in the acces, you can just make out the catch.

Refit is reversal, it's useful to practice with cylinder out to make sure the you can reset the catch.